# Django: support token authentication and session/cookie authentication at the same time?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
    url(r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
]
```

Password/Username are required to access the above two views.
Now, I am trying to add some APIs, it is possible to keep the above password authentication and add token authentication for the API below?

```
    url(r'^api/', api, 'api'),
```

Is it possible to use class [BasicCustomBackend(object)](http://blog.apcelent.com/django-json-web-token-authentication-backend.html) and class [JWTAuthentication(object)](http://blog.apcelent.com/django-json-web-token-authentication-backend.html) at the same time? Any examples?

**Any comments welcomed.** Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I am using [ModelBackend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py). But I have no idea how to access request from inside this class.

Comment: of coarse its possible .... in your authentication method just check for a token and use it if present ... if not just fallback on normal auth ... or check for normal auth... if its present great... if not check for a token ... you will ofc need to write your own authentication method(as described in your first link)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks. please see my update.